# CoordinatorLayout + AppBarLayout + Transparent Status Bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-design-library

My Scenario

I have an Activity(min SDK 19) with Coordinator and AppBar with Image and Scroll Behaviors, everything works fine except my status bar is not transparent nor translucent. Below is my

`<style name="AppTheme.Collapsing">
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
  </style>`

And I set that style to that Activity in manifest. Below is my xml layout.

These are images what I really want and what I got.

[image: I got like that, no transparent status bar.]
[image: I want like that, with transparent status bar.]
[image: After scroll top, this is the result. This is ok.]
Image 1. I got like that, no transparent status bar. 
Image 2. I want like that, with transparent status bar. 
Image 3. Result after scroll, this is ok.

```
`<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/splash"
                android:id="@+id/expandedImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"/>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/include_match_detail"/>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>


<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_logo"/>
```

`

Answer (score -1):

You can try this style file

```
styles.xml;

 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
 <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">

    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

also you need to create style for API Level 21

```
styles.xml for v21;
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/transparent</item>

    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

then in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file you need to specify your style for your application

```
AndroidManifest.xml

<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        ...
</application>
```

Another issue that i encounter when i try to make layout with transparent status.
I needed to put xml layout content inside `DrawerLayout` to make status bar transparent.

Answer (score -1):

Change all `android:fitsSystemWindows` attribute from "true" to "false", this may help you get a translucent status bar,
but after you do this, your `collapsingbarlayout` is collapsed and the title in your toolbar may be shown in the status bar,
then you can try add `android:layout_marginTop` attribute in your toolbar and set its value to "20dp".